How to move one or more vertices to the same position as the 'leading' vertex?
This is really just an exercise to learn more Mel, more than anything else. I gave myself a simple task of taking a number of vertices and moving them all to the same position as the 'leading' vertex (the one selected first).
Here is what I have:
string $sel[]= `ls -flatten -orderedSelection`;        //get all the selected vertice into an array
$attr = `getAttr $sel[1]`;                             // query the position of the first selected vertex
print($sel);                                           // I get expected results (three vertices = three elements)
print($attr);                                           // position of the first vertex does get returned


// Here is where I am stuck; setting the postion of the vertices to the first one
//setAttr $sel[0].x 5;                                   // Error: Syntax error
//setAttr $sel[0] $attr ;                               // Error: No object matches name: 

//move $attr;                                            // more errors
//move  $sel[0] $sel[1] ;                                  // more errors
//matchTransform  $sel[0] $sel[1];                          // more errors

Where I am stuck on seems to be setting the vertex position. I searched around and the answers seem to be pointing to setAttr but I am not sure where I am going wrong.
I asked a similar question before, how to set the 'axis orientation' option for the current tool?, this is my attempt to programme a solution to it.
